# How to fix "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: author is a required argument that is missing." in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command for my bot that allows users to make a bug report, but I keep getting an error when I try to run the code.

```py
@client.command()
async def bug(ctx, author, message, m):
    await ctx.send("Greetings! What would you like to report?")
    return m.author == message.author and m.channel == message.channel
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=bug)
    bugReport = msg[2:]
    await ctx.send("Thank you for your help. This bug has been reported to the server admins.")
    channel = client.get_channel(private)
    await channel.send(bugReport + " was reported by " + author)
```

The program is supposed to ask the user what they would like to report before taking in their error message and then switching to a bug report channel to report the problem, but instead, all I get is the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: author is a required argument that is missing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reusing the name `bug` to refer to both the command itself and the check for  `wait_for`.  It also looks like you're trying to define a check in the function, but you're missing the definition line.

You seem to expect `author` and `message` (and `m`, whatever that is) to be passed to the coroutine when the command is invoked.  Instead, they are bundled into a single [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context) object, which is the first argument.

Below, I have modified your code so it can take `report` from the initial invocation, or ask for it.

```
@client.command()
async def bug(ctx, *, report):
    def check(message):
        return ctx.author == message.author and ctx.channel == message.channel

    if not report:
        await ctx.send("Greetings! What would you like to report?")
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        report = msg.content[2:]  # This doesn't look right to me, will remove 2 characters
    await ctx.send("Thank you for your help. This bug has been reported to the server admins.")
    channel = client.get_channel(private)
    await channel.send(report + " was reported by " + author)
```

Comment: The [:2] was apart of an old feature. Thanks for pointing that out. Sorry for the poor everything in my code. I'm new to discord.py.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that required parameter `author` is missing.

There are 3 `author` parameters in your code above:

1. In the function `def bug(ctx, author, message, m)`
2. In the parameter `m.author`
3. In the parameter `message.author`

Add some `if author is not None:` statements in your code to check the `author` parameter is exist and set it to `None` by default if it is not required:

```
def bug(ctx, author=None, message, m):
    # Some code here...
    if author is not None:
        await channel.send(bugReport + " was reported by " + author)
    else:
        await channel.send(bugReport)  # without author
```

P.S. After `return` statement:

```
return m.author == message.author and m.channel == message.channel
```

the rest of the `bug` function will be not executed (useless).

Comment: Should I get rid of the async? Because if I do so I get an unknown invalid syntax on the next line.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not good at asynchronous input-output yet. You should [read this article](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) about `async` to understand the syntax of your code.